# How to fix a method that decides is tree a balanced tree or not?

Tags: java, avl-tree

For example, I have a tree:

```
                              8
                            _   _
                           /     \ 
                         1       48
                        /       /  \
                       0       40   50
                              /
                             10
```

When I add 10 to the TREE, my method decides, that this AVL tree is not an AVL tree and tries to balance it. I don't understand why the `isAVLTree` method does not work.

```
public static boolean isAVLTree(Root root) {
        return (findMaxDepth(root) - findMinDepth(root)) <= 1;
    }
```

```
public static int findMaxDepth(Root root) {
        if (root == null ) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.max(findMaxDepth(root.leftSide), findMaxDepth(root.rightSide));
    }
```

```
 public static int findMinDepth(Root root) {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return 1 + Math.min(findMinDepth(root.leftSide), findMinDepth(root.rightSide));
}
```

Сurrently the method `isAVLTree` returns `false`, because

```
(findMaxDepth(root) - findMinDepth(root)) <= 1
((         4        -        2)           <= 1 )   ->>>>>>>>>>>>>> FALSE
```

Comment: nodeOf(1).right has a depth of 1 whereas nodeOf(10) gives 3.

Answer (score 0):

> In an AVL tree, the heights of the two child subtrees of any node differ by at most one

([AVL Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree))

That's not what you implemented in your `isAVLTree` method. The difference between the max depth and min depth doesn't have to be <= 1.

Instead, you should require that both the left and right sub-trees are AVL trees, and in addition the difference between the heights of the left and right sub-trees <= 1.

```
public static boolean isAVLTree(Root root) 
{
    if (root == null) {
        return true;
    }

    return Math.abs(findMaxDepth(root.leftSide) - findMaxDepth(root.rightSide)) <= 1 &&
        isAVLTree (root.rightSide) &&
        isAVLTree (root.leftSide);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your method is correct ? It returns only true all the time

Comment: @SergeiE. I haven't tested it, but it seems to match the definition of AVL tree. Can you give an example of a tree where it returns true when you think it shouldn't?

Comment: Add elements : 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 ->5... Then element "2" added, it must return false, but return true

Comment: @SergeiE. what's the structure of the tree after you add these elements? I don't have your code.

Comment: `
Add: 0,  return tree : 0(_,_) ;  isAVLtree = true
Add: 1,  return tree :  0(_,1(_,_)) ;   isAVLtree = true
Add: 2,  return tree : 0(_,1(_,2(_,_))) ;   isAVLtree = true
Add: 3,  return tree : 0(_,1(_,2(_,3(_,_)))) ;   isAVLtree = true
Add: 4,  return tree : 0(_,1(_,2(_,3(_,4(_,_))))) ;   isAVLtree = true
`

Comment: @SergeiE. Oh, I see where I went wrong. Let me fix that. Fixed